# Every Cauchy net is convergent

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, banach-spaces, nets

Prove that in a Banach space every Cauchy net is convergent.

I have trouble to prove this, please help.Thanks

Edit:Let $A$ be a directed set and $\{f_{\alpha}\}_{\alpha\in A}$ is a net in $X$ topological space then $\{f_{\alpha}\}_{\alpha\in A}$  is cauchy net if $\forall \varepsilon>0$ there is $\alpha_0$ such that  $$\|f_{\alpha_1}-f_{\alpha_2}\|<\varepsilon \hspace{0.5cm} \forall \alpha_1,\alpha_2\geq\alpha_0$$

Comment: @user161825 thanks.But i don't understand that why "sequence $\langle x_{i(k)}:k\in\Bbb N\rangle$ is $d$-Cauchy"

Comment: (1) A Banach space is, by definition, a complete metric space, using the metric induced by the norm. (2) Consult the reference given by @user161825.

Comment: @RizwanAhmed. Pick $\varepsilon>0$. Choose $N\in\mathbb N$ so large that $2^{-N}<\varepsilon$. If $n,m$ are natural numbers exceeding $N$ and $n\geq m$ (with no loss of generality), then $$d(x_{i(n)},x_{i(m)})\leq2^{-m}<2^{-N}<\varepsilon$$ by the construction of the sequence $\{x_{i(k)}\}_{k\in\mathbb N}$ from the Cauchy net $\{x_i\}_{i\in I}$.

Comment: @triple_sec thanks for the help

Comment: @RizwanAhmed You're welcome!